# CreateFileW for READ_CONTROL fails with "Access is denied" despite being owner of the file

Tags: python, windows, acl, pywin32, dacl

On Windows, even if discretionary ACL (DACL) is empty, i.e. no one has permission to the file, file owner can read and write DACL (`READ_CONTROL` and `WRITE_DAC` access).

So I tried to do the following:

1. Set an empty DACL on a file
2. Obtain a handle to the file for `READ_CONTROL`
3. Obtain security descriptor using `GetSecurityInfo` and the handle
4. Check that the DACL is actually empty

However, obtaining the handle using `CreateFileW` failed with `Access is denied` error. Surprisingly, `GetFileSecurity`, which is an equivalent of `GetSecurityInfo` for files, worked fine. 
According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getfilesecuritya#remarks), `GetFileSecurity` requires `READ_CONTROL` access.

Why does `CreateFileW` fail in the following example?

```
import sys
import win32security
import win32con
import win32file
import ntsecuritycon
import os

path = sys.argv[1]

with open(path, "w"):
    pass  # I am the owner of the file

print("Set empty ACL")
sd = win32security.GetFileSecurity(path, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
dacl = win32security.ACL()
sd.SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(1, dacl, 0)
win32security.SetFileSecurity(path, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, sd)

try:
    print("Ensure that ACL is empty with GetFileSecurity")
    sd = win32security.GetFileSecurity(path, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
    dacl = sd.GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()
    assert 0 == dacl.GetAceCount()

    print("Try to ensure that ACL is empty using handle")
    handle = win32file.CreateFileW(
        path,
        ntsecuritycon.READ_CONTROL,
        0,
        None,  # security attributes
        win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        None,
    )
    sd = win32security.GetSecurityInfo(handle, win32security.SE_FILE_OBJECT, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
    dacl = sd.GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()
    assert 0 == dacl.GetAceCount()
except Exception as e:
    print("FAILURE:", e)
finally:
    print("Restore inherited ACEs before removing file")
    dacl = win32security.ACL()
    win32security.SetNamedSecurityInfo(
        path, 
        win32security.SE_FILE_OBJECT, 
        win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
        None,
        None,
        dacl,
        None
    )
    os.unlink(path)
```

Output:

```
> python acl-test.py file
Set empty ACL
Ensure that ACL is empty with GetFileSecurity
Try to ensure that ACL is empty using handle
FAILURE: (5, 'CreateFileW', 'Access is denied.')
Restore inherited ACEs before removing file
```

Comment: the `CreateFileW` api implicit add  `SYNCHRONIZE|FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` access. so  when you call `CreateFileW` with `READ_CONTROL` you really ask for `READ_CONTROL|SYNCHRONIZE|FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` - solution here - use `NtOpenFile`

Comment: `SetFileSecurity` is deprecated. It doesn't implement inheritance. Use `SetNamedSecurityInfo` instead, as you used in the `finally` block.

Comment: This doesn't apply to an empty DACL, but you should be aware that, since Vista (2006), Windows has an "OWNER_RIGHTS" security principal that sets the rights of an object's owner (roughly equivalent to the owner permissions in POSIX). If this is set in a DACL, it overrides the implicitly granted owner rights, `READ_CONTROL` and `WRITE_DAC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CreateFileW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) internally calls [`NtCreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntcreatefile) with the `DesiredAccess` parameter passed as `dwDesiredAccess | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES | SYNCHRONIZE`. Thus if you pass `dwDesiredAccess` as `READ_CONTROL`, then it actually tries to open the file with `READ_CONTROL | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES | SYNCHRONIZE` access. `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` access is granted implicitly by the file system if the caller has `FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY` access for the parent folder. However, `SYNCHRONIZE` access will not be granted if the file has an empty DACL.

One solution here would be to use [`NtOpenFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntopenfile) or `NtCreateFile` in order to control the exact requested access.

Comment: In the general case `CreateFileW` requires synchronize access because it opens the file in `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT` mode. However, it even requests this access for asynchronous I/O (i.e.  `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`) in order to allow synchronizing on the File object. Though doing so is generally discourage for asynchronous access.

Comment: If the caller has SeBackupPrivilege or SeRestorePrivilege, another solution is to enable either privilege in order to be granted synchronize access. Or simply use `GetNamedSecurityInfoW` and `SetNamedSecurityInfoW`, which internally call `NtOpenFile` without requesting unnecessary access.